# KVM kernel requires an x86-64 processor

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm installing `Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit` in `virt-manager`. When booting I have the
following error:

`This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate to your CPU.`

It should work because

```
$ kvm-ok 
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: You've setup your VM to use a 32-bit (i686), but are using an amd64 ISO so it won't work. Either enable to it run amd64 (64-bit) or use a i386 ISO

Comment: @guiverc Please, how to enable it to run amd64? I have chosen in CPU configuration > model > Clear CPU configuration, because it has written `incompatible CPU` before. My CPU is `$ inxi -C
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5 M 430 (-MT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
           clock speeds: max: 2267 MHz 1: 1332 MHz 2: 1581 MHz 3: 1569 MHz 4: 1616 MHz
`